# What is the correct regex (for PHP preg_replace) to remove empty paragraph ( <p> ) tags?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm working in Wordpress and need to be able to remove images and empty paragraphs. So far, I've found out how to remove images without a problem. But, I then need to remove empty paragraph tags. I'm using PHP preg_replace to handle the regex functions.

So, as an example, I have the string:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><img src="http://www.blah.com/image.jpg" alt="Blah Image" /></p><p>Some text</p>
```

I run this regex on it:

```
/<img.*?(>)/
```

And I end up with this string:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"></p><p>Some text</p>
```

I then need to be able to remove the empty paragraph. I tried this, but it removes all paragraphs and the contents of the paragraphs:

```
/<p[^>]*><\/p[^>]*>/
```

Any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried it on http://regexpal.com/ and it matched fine for the sample string...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 and then use another solution intended for parsing HTML, such as XSLT, DOM, or http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Kyte Thanks! The regex does work. I now realize that there are some other issues at play that will need addressed first.

Comment: re: XSLT - Normally yes, but this is coming from _wordpress_, meaning nine times out of ten someone pasted it from MS Word, and it's not valid _anything_ (besides a string).

Comment: He's not parsing HTML, he's just stripping a few tags. I think this is a reasonable approach, but @matthewpavkov, your task will become orders-of-magnitude easier if you use a character other than '/' to delimit your regular expressions. Then you don't have to escape forward-slashes in the body of your expression. The '#' character is a typical substitute, for example: '#<p[^>]*></p[^>]*>#'. BTW, your regex works as intended for me in PHP 5.2.6, using preg_replace().

Comment: @no: Right, XSLT and DOM are picky about well-formed XHTML, but SimpleHtmlDom is designed to handle imperfect markup.

Comment: @Bill I didn't even know I could change the escape character. I've just always seen a / so I figured that's how it had to be.

Comment: PHP is one of the few languages I've seen where you can do that. I end up using ~ a lot.

Comment: @no: Perl also supports alternative regex delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regex is **no regex**. Use an HTML/DOM Parser instead. They're simple to use. Regex is for regular languages (which HTML is not).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll have to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

`/<p[^>]*><\/p[^>]*>/` (the regex you gave) should work fine. If it's giving you trouble you could try double-escaping the `/` like this: `/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/`

PHP is funny about quoting and escape characters. For example `"\n"` is not equal to `'\n'`. The first is a line break, the second is a literal backslash followed by an 'n'. The PHP manual entry on string literals is probably worth a quick look.

Comment: "/n" and '/n' are identical; each is a two-character string consisting of a forward-slash followed by an 'n'. Also, your double-escape suggestion would introduce a spurious backslash into the regexp.

Comment: Heh, those were supposed to be backslashes. The double-escape is needed if it's inside a single quoted string but not a double quoted one, I think. Let me double check.

Comment: The double-escape suggestion doesn't insert any extra characters into the regex. It doesn't help either though. In fact it does nothing.